# Splitting strings separately by line and by blank space (using getline)

Tags: c++, vector, delimiter, getline

I am trying to read in lines of standard input and put each string on a line (separated by a space) into an index of a vector of vector strings, and then put each line in a separate index, but I'm confused how i would do this with getline.

Example, say my stdin is:

```
Hello
I want a
sand wich
```

The vector of string vectors would look like:

```
0: {"Hello"}
1: {"I", "want", "a"}
2: {"sand", "wich"}
```

I'm trying to code something like this:

```
vector <vector <string> > name;
string line, s;
int count= -1;
while(getline(cin, line, '\n'))
{
    count++;
    while (getline(line, s, ' '))
    {
        name[count].push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Would this do what I am trying to do?

Oh so with a string stream, like this?

```
vector <vector <string> > name;
string line, string;
stringstream ss;
int count= -1;
while(getline(cin, line, '\n'))
{
    count++;
    ss.str(line);
    while (ss >> string)
    {
        name[count].push_back(string);
    }
    ss.clear();
}
```

Comment: 1) You can try to run it and see. 2) If it doesn't compile, think about `vector[count].push_back` . ***After your update***: why do you need `vector< vector< string > >` ?

Comment: You would need to use a stringstream for your second getline.

Comment: Because the program I'm writing needs to store the information in a vector of string vectors. It's for a class. And I thought you could use getline to cin into a string? I think my teacher has done that before.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code .

```
vector <vector <string> > name;
vector<string> tmp;
string line, str;//It should not be string
stringstream ss;
int count= -1;//no need for count variable as pushing to a vector starts from 0
while(getline(cin, line, '\n'))
{
    count++;
    ss.str(line);
    while(ss >> str)
    {
        tmp.push_back(str);//extracting tokens of string in tmp vector
    }
    name.push_back(tmp);//pushing vector of string to main vector
    tmp.clear();
    ss.clear();
}
```